# How to start Prometheus logging things?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Recently I've installed Grafana and Prometheus on the server to have some monitoring dashboard.

I've added some dashboards:

[image]

But there is **no data** for almost all of them. You can see some of the dashboards screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

See? All are in No Data status. Since they are based on Prometheus, so I guess I need to make Prometheus force to start logging things. Any idea how can I do that?

Noted that, I've also added MySQL database as another data source and wrote some queries on the tables and it works well and I can see this dashboard:

[image]

---

Also, here is the content of current `prometheus.yml` file:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

Comment: To make Prometheus gather data you need to add scrape jobs to its config file. A scrape job is essentially a piece of config describing how to pull metrics from exporters (=applications that expose metrics) over HTTP. Better start with the documentation https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/

Comment: Ah I see @anemyte, Thx for providing the link

Comment: I've added the content of `prometheus.yml` file to my question @anemyte. You mean I have to add something there? (something named scrape)

Comment: You have one job already - Prometheus scrapes itself for metrics. Now you need to add the stuff that you want to monitor. One popular example https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter

Comment: Ok @anemyte, Thanks for mentioning that great dashboard, [I imported it as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Eoc.png) and [applied the needed changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zCZ.png), but still no data `:-(`. Any comment?

Comment: Also, I [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEuu2.png) can give you a clue

Comment: Ok I made it working !!! Yay ...